# Stuck at SSIS logic

Tags: ssis, etl

**Scenario:**

I have four records, each have four properties (for example : 1. Length(number), 2. IsStudent(bool), 3.IsSenior(bool), 4.Tagname(string)),

My condition is

**I need to insert one record in a table for each of the four records if IsStudent is Yes or IsSenior is Yes or Length is not null or Tagname is not null.**

For example:

A record with 1. Length(null), 2. IsStudent(Yes), 3.IsSenior(No), 4.Tagname(null) will insert a record

A record with 1. Length(10), 2. IsStudent(No), 3.IsSenior(No), 4.Tagname(null) will insert a record

A record with 1. Length(null), 2. IsStudent(No), 3.IsSenior(No), 4.Tagname(null) will **not** insert a record

How can i do this in SSIS package?

**Screenshot of my package:**

[image]

Please advise. How can i do this?

For the above screenshot, i need to insert a single record with id 2094 and a single records with id 2095 (total 2 out of 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do it in the dataflow, you can do it with a script transformation.

But if you can, it would be better to import all rows to a staging table, and then filter out the rows you don't want to insert in a stored procedure that inserts the rows you want to the final destination table.